# How to set fixed major tics in log scale with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put a number of tics in the y axis of a plot with inverted logarithmic scale. In particular, I'd like to have the 1000, 900, 800... etc values labelled.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

%matplotlib nbagg


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,4))

ax.set_ylim(200,1000)
ax.set_xlim(-60,40)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

ax.set_yscale('log')
majors = np.array([1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200])

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(majors))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormater())

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

plt.xlabel('Temp (ºC)')
plt.ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')


plt.savefig(fname='test.png', dpi = 200)
plt.close()
```

And this is the figure I get: [image]

As you can see, the tics in the y axis are being placed by default, not as I want them to be. My call to `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(majors))` seems to be ignored. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to *first* set the scale to a log scale and *then* change its locators.

Comment: I have changed the order as suggested but the problem remains. The major tics are placed where they want.

Comment: When I run your code I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/176X2.png) which I think is what you want.